# GT-P1000 pc and phone icon

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab, unbricking, odin

I was trying to root my old Galaxy Tab 7 (GT-P1000) device when it got frozen at the setup connection. I noticed then that it was a Gingerbread file -- so I killed Odin. Now I'm getting phone and exclamation mark and a PC.

Can somebody please help me solve this? I've been searching the Internet and didn't find anything.

Please note that Odin still recognizes/sees the device.

**Edit:** to clarify, this was the [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPSBXC72rmg) video on '*How to Unbrick Samsung Galaxy Tab P1000*' that was used and ended up right now as per the question above.

Comment: Clarify exactly what you're doing - you're rooting and where does Odin come in? Show us the link or instructions that you got it from to enable us to help you.

Comment: This one worked http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPSBXC72rmg, 
How to Unbrick Samsung Galaxy Tab P1000

Comment: rooting or unbricking... which is it?

Comment: Let me see if I understood your question: You were trying to root your tablet but you killed Odin, so your tablet got bricked. The video you talk about is what you found to try to unbrick your device, but that didn't help. Am I right? "Now I'm getting phone and exclamation mark and a PC." I don't understand this part, though. Are they icons? Where do you see the exclamation mark? Where do you see the PC? What operating system are you using in your PC?

Comment: I'm using windows with odin 3, I was trying to root the phone but it failed for some reason then I unplugged the cable then I got the phone and pc icons, then I followed the you tube video to restore it back